# What material is best to design a dipole antenna working at VHF frequency?

Tags: antenna, antenna-construction, vhf, dipole

I need to design an antenna using the tool FEKO. 
The antenna is supposed to work in VHF frequency and has a gain of around 2.2 dB.
What is the best material to use and what are the specifications of the materials that I need to consider before designing the antenna?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very generic answer, but I would avoid metals such as steel, and go with the more popular conductors like Copper or Aluminum.

I have several aluminum VHF antennas and they work great.